# Haskell- parse error on input

Tags: haskell

I have the following code which
halves each even number in a list:

```
halfEvens :: [Int] -> [Int]
halfEvens [xs]  
   | x `mod` 2 == 0 = x `div` 2
   | otherwise      = x
   where x <- xs
```

And I get the following error:

```
parse error on input '<-'
```

I was careful so I respected the indentations...any other ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two main issues in your code:

1. `where` block defines functions, so, you should use `=` instead of `<-`
2. Your function accepts lists with exactly one element inside

Instead of it I suggest you write separate function `halfIfEven`:

```
Prelude> let halfIfEven x = if even x then x `div` 2 else x
```

Then define `halfEvens` using `map`:

```
Prelude> let halfEvens = map halfIfEven
Prelude> halfEvens [1..10]
[1,1,3,2,5,3,7,4,9,5]
```

But, of course, you could write this using pattern matching, although it is less readable:

```
halfIfEven :: Int -> Int
halfIfEven x | even x    = x `div` 2
             | otherwise = x

halfEvens :: [Int] -> [Int]
halfEvens []     = []
halfEvens (x:xs) = (halfIfEven x):(halfEvens xs)
```